# Was "Seamstress" used as a euphemism for sex workers in real life?

Tags: euphemisms

Terry Pratchett's *Discworld* series uses "seamstress" as a euphemism for sex worker. Prior to the publication of the series, was it used in real life this way?

It sounds very plausible, but neither Wiktionary nor the Online Etymology Dictionary mentions it.

Comment: Upvote for the question as it's always interesting to explore how much authors have played fast and loose with/been faithful to real-world origins in created-world writings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is mentioned in the [Encyclopedia of Prostitution and Sex Work Vol 2](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-5WyPfynlwMC&lpg=PA431&ots=Ssdy0-mpKn&dq=seamstress%20euphemism&pg=PA431#v=onepage&q=seamstress%20euphemism&f=false) ISBN 0-313-32970-2 Pub 2006 Greenwood Press

> SEAMSTRESSES. "Seamstress" was a euphemism for "prostitute" in census records and other documents of the 19th century in the United States. Historical documentation showing several "seamstresses" sharing common living quarters may generally be assumed to represent a brothel. Whether this occupation was reported by prostitutes or supplied by census enumerators and other officials remains speculative, although potential reasons for both are easily understood.
>   Legitimate uses of the term should not be confused with the codified use. Other historical and modern euphemisms exist, including **laundressess** and **actressess**.

[New Essays on Poe's Major Tales by Kenneth Silverman](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=eP03AAAAIAAJ&lpg=PA86&ots=eTOM64Yms6&dq=seamstress%20euphemism&pg=PA90#v=onepage&q=seamstress%20euphemism&f=false), Cambridge University Press 1993 also states:

> Terms like "shopgirl" and "seamstress" were mid-century euphemisms for
>   women whose chief source of income was their bodies.

This [website](http://rictornorton.co.uk/though13.htm) also discusses the issue with reference to an older work by [Charles Horne](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hLpYAAAAcAAJ&ots=6KjjLMgxm8&vq=seamstress&dq=text%20Charles%20Horne%20%20Serious%20Thoughts%20on%20the%20Miseries%20of%20Seduction%20and%20Prostitution&pg=PA52#v=onepage&q=seamstressess&f=false)

> In John Cleland's Fanny Hill Mrs Cole's establishment poses as a
>   "millinery shop". A milliner's or mantua-maker's establishment was
>   often likened to a house of prostitution, probably an accurate public
>   perception.
>
> A good many of the fallen women whose bastard children were put into
>   the Foundling Hospital were seamstresses. Millinery and dressmaking
>   were a kind of introduction to the prostitute's trade. What trial
>   records show is that when prostitutes were brought into court (usually
>   for stealing a gentleman's watch while his trousers were down), they
>   would describe themselves as apprentices to a mantua-maker, or as
>   being at one time a mantua-marker before they were led astray. A
>   character witness for a prostitute will commonly be a mantua-maker,
>   but I think many judges and juries realized that this mantua-maker
>   acted as the "aunt" at the head of a small-time ring of streetwalkers.
>   The professional mantua-maker often took in lodgers to supplement her
>   income, and the real situation, often as not, is that she would have a
>   few girl "apprentices" who mended stolen clothes and made new clothes
>   from stolen textiles while they are not otherwise engaged picking up
>   men in the street and bringing them to their mistress's upstairs
>   rooms. It was not uncommon for a gentleman to go into a milliner's
>   shop and have sex with one of the girls then and there. Though
>   dressmaking could of course involve a high degree of professional
>   skill, it also provided good cover for both prostitution and fencing
>   stolen goods. Very large quantities of linen and silk, plus ribbons
>   and lace etc., were regularly stolen from warehouses, and found their
>   way to mantua-makers, milliners, and tailors. Tailors and milliners
>   often acted as pawnbrokers, which to a great extent meant dealing in
>   stolen goods. They operated on the boundary between the underworld and
>   the respectable world.
>
> The occupation of millinery or mantua-making was widely regarded as
>   just a cover for prostitution. **[Charles Horne in Serious Thoughts on
>   the Miseries of Seduction and Prostitution (1783)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hLpYAAAAcAAJ&ots=6KjjLMgxm8&vq=seamstress&dq=text%20Charles%20Horne%20%20Serious%20Thoughts%20on%20the%20Miseries%20of%20Seduction%20and%20Prostitution&pg=PA52#v=onepage&q=seamstressess&f=false)** warned parents not
>   to allow their daughters to become milliners, mantua-makers, or
>   workers in the various clothes trades because they were "actually
>   seminaries of prostitution".

Comment: Looks like there's an encyclopedia for everything under the sun. Great!

Comment: It even comes in several volumes ;)

Comment: “. . . we cannot lodge and board a dozen or fourteene Gentlewomen that liue honeſtly by the pricke of their Needles, but it will bee thought we keepe a Bawdy-house ſtraight.”—Hostess in Shakespeare’s *Henry V* 2.1.

Comment: @BrianDonovan ::snigger:: he said ‘prick’ ::snigger::

Answer (score 2):

I attach a Census image from 1881 of Devonshire Street in St. George in the East, London which has a number of properties where the young female occupants (all lodgers) from many countries have a range of occupations such as dressmaker, laundress, etc. but who were almost certainly prostitutes.

Emily Brown at No. 19 even has a gentleman visitor who presumably chose not to reveal his name which is registered as "N.K".

Interestingly Sarah Pipman on the bottom line does not have a euphemism.

[image: 1881 Census for St. George in the East, London]

Answer (score 0):

In Cambridge (England) there used to be a special police force that had the power to arrest women “walking in the company of a member of the university” and imprisoning them in the “spinning house”, where they were actually set to work spinning. This continued until as late as 1891.

https://www.theguardian.com/science/the-h-word/2012/oct/19/history-science

Answer (score 0):

Many single female immigrants from countries like Sweden came over as seamstresses, dressmakers ( those terms were defined differently in NYC) and tailors. These were jobs that they'd held in big cities and could be done immediately without extensive knowledge of English language in an era before mass production of clothing. Let's not forget the devastating Triangle Shirtwaist Fire in New York City that killed the clothing workers and that resulted in revised labor laws. I would like a timeframe and much more clarity in information about specific locations before generalizing a description of clothing workers as ladies of the evening. We know there were plenty of those (prostitutes), but cooking,servant work, laundry work and dressmaking were among the few legit jobs women could hold initially in urban America.

Comment: No one was suggesting that all clothing workers were ladies of the evening, rather that terms from one profession could be *euphemistically* applied to the other, in circumstances where the fiction was both convenient and (most importantly) *understood*..